# Dropbox and inotifywait

Tags: shell, dropbox, inotify

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -e modify -e create -e delete /home/me/Dropbox/text; do
    touch testscriptworked
done
```

With the script running, when I make changes to the actual text directory in Dropbox, inotifywait picks it up. But if I use a text editor on my iPad linked to that Dropbox folder, inotifywait never picks it up.

I'm pretty new to this so anything will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

its because alot of mobile apps ive seen, by just randomly watching inotifywait verbose,
arent triggering create events when something is created.

the event you wanna watch for is ATTRIB.